# how to draw a unfinished data point bar in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to present some experiment comparisons. One of the candidate (SHJ) takes too long to run.
Could anyone give me some suggestions on how to present such data point in a bar chart?
Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
dataset ptsj    shj pretti  pplus   ptsj-meta   shj-meta    pretti-meta pplus-meta
flickr  1093    86400   343.4222446 302.8254    3.6x    nan 1.1x    1.0x
orkut   5238    86400   14400   1333.03325  3.9x    nan 10.8x   1.0x
twitter 1671    6051    16213.23523 15046.2471  1.0x    3.6x    9.7x    9.0x
webbase 242.88  2679.67 1703    695 1.0x    11.0x   7.0x    2.9x
}\realdata


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    height=6cm,
    width=1\columnwidth,
    ybar,
    ymax=50000,
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    symbolic x coords={flickr,orkut,twitter,webbase},
    xtick={flickr,orkut,twitter,webbase},
    ymode=log,
    y label style={at={(0.05,0.5)}},
    ylabel=elapsed time (s),
    %x tick label style={rotate=25,anchor=east},
    bar width=8pt,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
nodes near coords,
point meta=explicit symbolic,
every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
after end axis/.code={
\node[anchor=west] at (rel axis cs:0,1.05){$>10^5$};
\node[anchor=west] at (rel axis cs:0.25,1.05){$>10^5$};
},
    %cycle list name=exotic,
]
\addplot[draw=black,pattern color=black,pattern=horizontal lines] table[x=dataset,y=shj, meta=shj-meta] {\realdata};
\addplot[draw=black,pattern color=blue,pattern=north east lines] table[x=dataset,y=pretti,meta=pretti-meta] {\realdata};
\addplot[draw=black,pattern color=gray,pattern=crosshatch dots] table[x=dataset,y=ptsj, meta=ptsj-meta] {\realdata};
\addplot[draw=black,pattern color=white] table[x=dataset,y=pplus,meta=pplus-meta] {\realdata};

\legend{SHJ, PRETTI, PTSJ, PRETTI+}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]